# Gmail RSVP Actions not working

Tags: email, gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to send Event with RSVP Action, but there is no button showed in Gmail inbox. 
I am trying this code:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Taco Night"/>
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-18T15:30:00Z"/>
  <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2015-04-18T16:30:00Z"/>
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Google"/>
      <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="24 Willie Mays Plaza"/>
      <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
      <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
      <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94107"/>
      <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="USA"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction">
    <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=yes"/>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="attendance" href="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction">
    <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=no"/>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="attendance" href="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/No"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/RsvpAction">
    <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
      <link itemprop="url" href="http://example.com/rsvp?eventId=123&value=maybe"/>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="attendance" href="http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Maybe"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

It s same as in tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action. I am sending it via Google Code script to own email xxx@gmail.com. Does anybody know why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Martin Hromádko, in order for it to work, you would have to use a **startDate** that is in the future. Try changing your startDate and endDate, the RSVP action should work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I did not noticed that. Now it is working fine.